# How do I declare an 'operator' that takes 2 arguments and uses letters rather than symbols?

Tags: function, haskell

I want to be able to make operators such as found in VB(.net) like shown below

```
Console.WriteLine ( 16 Mod 2 )
```

produces an output shown below

```
0
```

As you can see, this makes code slightly easier to read. How would I go about making functions that do this?

I have tried the following format

```
equal :: Integer -> Integer -> bool
x `equal` y = x == y
```

and I get the following error

```
*Main> 5 equal 5

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Num ((Integer -> Integer -> Bool) -> t -> t1)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t t1.
              (Num ((Integer -> Integer -> Bool) -> t -> t1), Num t) =>
              t1
*Main>
```

What is going wrong and how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use backticks around `equal` when you call it, exactly as you did to define it.

```
5 `equal` 5
```

The way you wrote it, Haskell thinks you're trying to pass `equal` as an argument to `5`, rather than the other way around.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. By the way, why do I need to use backticks when defining it. If I don't use them when defining, I get a compile error saying that the function lacks an accompanying binding

Comment: I found out that backticks are the way to do it by looking at the definition of xor in the Data.Boolean package but I don't know WHY they are needed.

Comment: @JamesYeoman All Haskell functions with non-symbolic names are ordinary prefix functions, not infix operators. You can turn an infix operator into a prefix function by surrounding it with parentheses (like `(+)`), and likewise, you can turn a prefix function into an infix operator by surrounding it with backticks (like `\`elem\``).

Comment: Thanks. I am teaching myself Haskell before we actually start learning it in Computer Science. It is my first Functional Programming language. Brain.exe is not responding...

Comment: @JamesYeoman If you wrote `x equals y = ...` that looks exactly the same to the compiler as `func a b = ...`. There's no possible way for it to know that in the first case  the **second** name is the function you're defining (and the other two are local names for its arguments), while in the other the first name is the function. So Haskell adopts a very simple syntactic rule: alphanumeric names are always prefix functions and symbolic names are always infix operators. That means `x equals y = ...` is defining a function `x`; `equals` is just a local name for one of its arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. All of this is going to help out a lot with the understanding when we come to actually start to be taught Haskell after Christmas. Every time I learn a new language, I always have a go teaching myself the language first before getting taught. It helps so much having the lessons when I have already got a basic understanding because I can then focus on the intricacies. Best of luck to you all with your goals